# Solving for Big Theta Notation

Tags: notation, asymptotic-complexity

I'm having an issue solving for big theta notation. I understand that big O notation denotes the worst case and upperbound while Omega notation denotes the best case and lower bound.

If I'm given an algorithm that runs in O(nlogn) time and Omega(n), how would I infer what Theta equals? I'm beginning to assume that there exists a theta notation if and only if O and Omega are equal, is this true?

Comment: Your understanding isn't correct; big-O is not the same as worst-case, Omega is not the same as best-case.

Comment: read this too http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Time_complexity#Table_of_common_time_complexities and http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Big_O_notation#Orders_of_common_functions

Comment: Let me guess, you are thinking about some sort of sorting algorithm, maybe heapsort: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Heapsort

Comment: if big O is not the worst case and omega is not the best case, what are they supposed to represent?

Comment: @user1364768: Upper and lower bounds, like you said.  But this is distinct from best and worst case.  (Consider that quicksort is O(n log n) best-case, for example.)

Answer (score 0):

Assume your algorithm runs in `f(x)`.

*`f(x) = O(n*log(n))` means that for `x` high enough there is some constant `c1 > 0` so that `f(x)` will always be smaller than `c1*n*log(n)`.*

*`f(x) = Omega(n)` means that for `x` high enough there is some constant `c2 > 0` so that `f(x)` will be bigger than `c2*n`*

So all you know now is that from a certain point onward (`x` big enough) your algorithm will run faster than `c2*n` and slower than `c1*n*log(n)`.

*`f(x) = Theta(g(x))` means that for `x` big enough there is some `c3 > 0` and `c4 > 0` so that `c3*g(x) <= f(x) <= c4*g(x)`, this means `f(x)` will only run a constant factor faster or slower than `g(x)`. So indeed, `f(x) = O(g(x))` and `f(x) = Omega(g(x))`.*

**Conclusion:** With only O and Omega given, if they are not the same you cannot conclude what Theta is. If you have the algorithm you could try and see if O was maybe chosen too high, or Omega might have been chosen too low.